# How do distributed applications verify that the data was processed correctly?

Tags: distributed-computing

There are a lot of projects out there that rely on the public sphere to process data for them, but I do wonder how they ensure that every computer participating has processed the data properly.

The first one that comes to mind is Bitcoin mining. I know that the Bitcoin network has a mathematical way of verifying that the data has been processed correctly (I'm not going to go into that here).

But, when I think about other projects, such as the [SETI@home](http://setiathome.ssl.berkeley.edu/) project, I often wonder how they know that every participant is behaving correctly; how is it that they know the data was actually processed, or that the results being returned are accurate. The only validation I can think of would require them to also process the same data, meaning that the distributed model is moot.

---

The game of connect four has already been solved, but let's say that someone wanted to develop a project that solved the game of connect four using a distributed public network (the internet). The server would send down a large chunk of data to one machine to process, for example it would send down a starting point and the machine would have to process all possible boards with a depth of 5 and use a predetermined formula for scoring, then return the best move to the server.

- How does the server know that this was the best move using the algorithm?
- How do we guarantee that there isn't a rogue actor that is consuming the service and replacing the predetermined scoring algorithm with a junk one that yields the incorrect best move?

Comment: Search for "set at home result verification" brings up (not surprisingly) [Result Verification](https://seti.berkeley.edu/setiathome/scinews/news8)

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about two different problems, *result verification* and *byzantine failure*.

For **result verification**, the general idea is to find a way to *verify* the answer more quickly than it can be *computed*. There are two approaches, which I will call *strong verification* and *weak verification*. Strong verification involves a *proof* that the result is (in)correct. For example, this is a defining characteristic of [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problems: an answer takes exponential time to compute but can be verified in polynomial time.

Weak verification can be used in situations where it is impossible to *prove* the correctness of a result, and only attempts to verify the result to within some acceptable confidence interval. This is typically a heuristic-based approach, such as [SETI@Home's result verification method](https://seti.berkeley.edu/setiathome/scinews/news8) (as mentioned by MichaelT).

**Byzantine** systems are those where processes can fail in arbitrary (including malicious) ways. There are a number of methods for achieving [Byzantine fault tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance). The most common is perhaps [state machine replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine_replication), where the critical step is *ordering inputs* to ensure that the replicas have a consistent view of the world.

Input ordering is commonly achieved via [*consensus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science)) algorithms. Consensus algorithms are pretty much what they sound like: a way to ensure that there is sufficient agreement about a data value within the system before it is used.

Byzantine failure is a complex problem and this is a very brief and necessarily incomplete summary. For more information, please use the included links and especially the references that they provide.

Comment: True for NP-complete problems. But for example for the travelling salesman problem, the NP-complete problem is "is there a tour of 639 miles or less" which can be verified. The real problem "what is the shortest tour" is not a YES/NO problem and doesn't belong to the class NP.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's a good point. Sometimes the NP-complete version of a problem isn't very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a global snapshot, in conjunction with an analysis algorithm can (and is) used for this type of verification.

> The [Snapshot Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_algorithm) works like this:
>
> ```
> The observer process (the process taking a snapshot):
>     Saves its own local state
>     Sends a snapshot request message bearing a snapshot token to all other processes
> A process receiving the snapshot token for the first time on any message:
>     Sends the observer process its own saved state
>     Attaches the snapshot token to all subsequent messages (to help propagate the 
>     snapshot token)
> Should a process that has already received the snapshot token receive
> a message that does not bear the snapshot token, this process
> will forward that message to the observer process. This message was obviously sent before 
> the snapshot “cut off” (as it does not bear a snapshot token and thus must have come from 
> before the snapshot token was sent out) and needs to be included in the snapshot.
> ```
>
> From this, the observer builds up a complete snapshot: a saved state
>   for each process and all messages “in the ether” are saved.

Once the observers have all generated a snapshot of their local state, a central analyzer can pull these snapshots, reconstruct them, and run verification on them.